# How to make a collection valued property read only in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I've got a collection valued property of a basic (non-entity) type that I want to make read only. I've managed to exclude the column from insert and update sql queries, but I cannot do the same for delete queries, so if the containing entity has an empty list of said property, all of them get deleted from the database:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "T_REL_PARENT_CHILD", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))

    private List<Long> childIds;
}
```

Comment: Same problem here