# Hibernate one-to-many to fetch only primary key column of the target entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have following two JPA entities : Company and Employee which follow one-to-many relationship :

```
Employee
---------
eId  |  eName   | company_id

Company
--------
cId  |  cName
```

I have been trying to fetch Employee IDs list in Company entity. **I tried with two ways - employees1 and employees2 as shown below. Both are not working**. Note that I want **List of Employee IDs and not the List of Employees.**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   String eId;
   String eName;
}

@Entity
public class Company{
   @Id
   String cId;
   String cName;

   // both of the below are not working
   
   @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, targtEntity = Employee.class )
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumn = "cId")
   @Column(name = "eId")
   Set<String> employees1 = new HashSet<>();
   

   @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", tableName = "Employee", referencedColumn = "cId")
   @Column(name = "eId")
   Set<String> employees2 = new HashSet<>();
}
```

For employees1, I am getting :  org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field.

For employees2 :  org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article by Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), it explains everything in great detail!
The optimal mapping would look like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String eId;

    private String eName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Company refundRequest;

    void setRefundRequest(Company refundRequest) {
        this.refundRequest = refundRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(eId, employee.eId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(eId);
    }
    
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    private String cId;

    private String cName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public void addEmployee(final Employee employee) {
        employee.setRefundRequest(this);
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    
    public void removeEmployee(final Employee employee) {
        employee.setRefundRequest(null);
        employees.remove(employee);
    }
    
}
```

Make sure to read the above mentioned article to understand why this mapping is optimal!

In order to fetch it, you can use a repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String> {

    @Query("select e.eId from Employee e where e.company = :company")
    List<String> findEmployeeIdsByCompany(@Param("company") Company company);

}
```

By the way, eager fetching is [a massive code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) and should be avoided!

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. OP doesn't want the `List<Employee>`, he wants the IDs only

Comment: @XtremeBaumer in order to being able to fetch it, you need to have a valid mapping in the first place. I added a repository method for the fetching logic.

Comment: While true, it is possible to get the IDs as a field with mapping in the `Company` directly

Comment: I need to have List of employeeIds, not the list of employees.

Comment: @shashank this is the way to go! As you can see the other propsed way does not work. You need to configure the mapping correctly, else it won't work as expected. Use the repository to query the IDs when you need them. Everything you need is in my post.

Answer (score 1):

`@ElementCollection` is the annotation you need to use in this case. `@CollectionTable` defines in which table you want to fetch the value from as well as on which column the join happens. `@Column` defines the column name you want to fetch from the `@CollectionTable`

```
@Entity
class Company {
    @Id
    String cId;
    String cName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"))
    @Column(name = "eId")
    Set<String> employeeIds = new HashSet();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but we have a problem here. If we do : 
Company c = new Company(); 
c.setId("A"); 
c.setName("Company A");
c.setEmployeeIds(Set.of("1","2"));

here, 1 and 2 are the ids of two employees which already exist in the database. 
But hibernate here is trying to insert two rows with id 1 and 2 into Employee tables, which is resulting in pk contraint violation

Comment: You could attempt `@Column(name = "eId", insertable = false)`

Comment: This option does not work

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720112/how-to-make-a-collection-valued-property-read-only-in-jpa), you can use `@Column(name = "eId", insertable = false, updateable = false)` to block inserts/updates, but not deletes. Depending on the actual use case, you might definitely be better of using a proper entity mapping to `Employee`. Or you just make sure that you can't alter the `employeeIds` collection within your code